# How to add decimal number to time and get it back as a time format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have time strings like this:

`6:28 PM`

And I have decimal numbers like this:

`2.36`

meaning "2hours and 36min"

I want to add the decimal number to the time to get it in this format:

`9:04 PM`

What's the best way to do this?

I'm also using moment.js on the page so if there's a way to do it through moment that would work also.

Comment: split your decimal into something more understandable, then use moment's data math functions with those "understandable" values.

Comment: You mean the whole "6:28 PM" is a string var?

Comment: @aln447 yes "6:28 PM" is a string, it's coming back from a 3rd party api request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment.add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

```
var add = 2.36;
var split = add.toString().split('.');
moment().add(split.shift(), 'hours').add(split.shift(), 'minutes');
```

Comment: This adds 2 hrs 36 min to the current time, not the initial strings I have like "6:28 PM". Is there a way to convert those strings into a moment object?

Comment: Yes: `moment(["today", "6:58 PM"].join(' '), 'h:mm a').add(4, 'hours').toDate()`